# Retrieve project's process in Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

We have migrated TFS to Azure DevOps Server 2019 (17.143.28621.4).
We want to know the migrated projects' process.

In Azure DevOps Service, this information is displayed on "Organization settings -> Projects" but not with Azure DevOps Server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/import-process/import-process

I try to find this information in the projects collection's database... without success.

Do you know how I can retreive the project's process in Azure DevOps Server?

Comment: Hi @Orwel Did you get a chance to try out the extension in below answer, How did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extension **[VSTS TeamProject Monitor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=canarysautomationspvtltd.VSTS-TeamProject-Monitor)** to get the project's process for Azure DevOps Server.

Go to extension Marketplace and search and install extension VSTS TeamProject Monitor. 
After it is installed, you will see **ProjectList** will be added to the **Extensions** section under **Collection** setttings.
[image]

Then you can go to Collection settings--> Extensions---> ProjectList. There you can find the project's process in the **Template** column

[image]

If you don't want to install above extension. You can go to **Boards**--> **Process**. There you will see a number for each process under **Team projects**, which indicates how many projects are using this process. You can click on these numbers to check what are those projects.

[image]

Comment: The project migrated from TFS has the template `Agile`. Do you think is normal?